# Pegar id da ultima venda e cadastrar no campo codvenda da tabela itens.

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,
tenho que cadastrar as vendas efetuadas em duas tabelas, (Venda e ItemVenda).

Na tabela venda tenho os campos id, codcliente, datavenda e total.

Na tabela itemvenda tenho os campos id, codvenda, quant, preco.

A minha dúvida é como pegar o conteúdo do campo id da tabela venda, e grava-lo no campo codvenda da tabela itemvenda, já que ambas são gravadas simultaneamente no ato da emissão do boleto bancário.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz nessa minha dúvida, ficarei muitíssimo agradecido.

Estou usando mysql e php.

Agradecido pela a atenção dos amigos.

Comment: faz uma procedure para isso, onde ela grava na tabela A, pega o id e depois vai inserir na tabela B já com o id do primeiro insert.

Comment: está usando POO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php) - Obtém o ID gerado pela operação INSERT anterior

```
<?php $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); 

if (!$link) { die('Erro na conexão: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db('mydb'); mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) 
values ('kossu')"); 

printf(ID inserido = %d\n", mysql_insert_id()); ?>
```

> Nota: Devido a mysql_insert_id() agir sobre a última consulta
>   realizada, tenha certeza de chamar mysql_insert_id() imediatamente
>   após a consulta que gerou o valor.
>
> Nota: O valor da função SQL do MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() sempre contém o
>   valor AUTO_INCREMENT mais recentemente gerado, e não é reiniciado
>   entre as consultas.

Comment: Com a sua dica durtto, eu consegui pegar e visualizar o id da venda, mas como faço para gravar este mesmo id no campo codvenda da tabela itemvenda. Tem como vc. me dar uma dica. Desde já agradeço a sua atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Com a dica do Durtto e muito chute (Rs...), consegui pegar o id da venda e gravar no campo codvenda da tabela itemvenda.

Ficou assim o código php:

```
<?php

include '../conexao.php';

if(isset($_POST['bb'])){

$codcliente = $_POST['codcliente'];
$datavenda = date("d/m/Y");
$total = $_POST['total'];

$query_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda (codcliente, total, datavenda) VALUES ('$codcliente', '$total', '$datavenda')")or die(mysql_error());
if($query_insert == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar Venda!');
          </script>";
}}

$codvenda = mysql_insert_id();
$codproduto = $_POST['codproduto'];
$quant = $_POST['quant'];
$preco = $_POST['preco'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemvenda (codvenda, codproduto, quant, preco) values ('$codvenda', '$codproduto', '$quant', '$preco')");
//printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());

?>
```

Valeu Durtto pela dica e a todos um grande abraço.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu. Parabéns.