# Fazer insert em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer um insert em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo. 
Tenho um cadastro de usuários e preciso que o id de um usuário seja cadastrado em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, assim fazendo uma associação deste usuário á uma outra tabela, que contém um grupo de usuários.

Comment: [Olhe essa resposta e veja se ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104719/pegar-id-da-ultima-venda-e-cadastrar-no-campo-codvenda-da-tabela-itens/104721#104721)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível fazer múltiplos `inserts` através de um `statement`, porém dentro de uma `transaction` sim:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO Tabela1 (Coluna1, ...) VALUES (....);
   INSERT INTO Tabela2 VALUES (..., LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT
```

Mais sobre o [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

No exemplo acima, tudo é feito pelo MySql. O `LAST_INSERT_ID()` vai pegar o valor da coluna que for `autoincrement` no primeiro insert. Se quiser utilizar PHP, você pode fazer:

`Insert into ....`

Pelo PHP, você consegue obter o ultimo valor inserido:

`$ultimo_valor_inserido = mysql_insert_id();`

Com um pequeno detalhe:

> Se a sua coluna AUTO_INCREMENT for uma coluna do tipo BIGINT, o valor retornado por mysql_insert_id() será incorreto. Ao invés, use a função SQL interna do MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() em uma consulta SQL.

Para mais informações, [consulte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Isso é com php, certo?

Comment: Pode me explicar mais sobre sua resposta?

Comment: Amigo, editei a resposta... Tudo é feito pelo Mysql, mas você também pode utilizar do mesmo artificio via PHP para poder  o ultimo registro inserido. Dá uma olhada na minha resposta editada, se tiver dúvida, volte a perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui inserir em duas tabelas fazendo assim: Fiz a primeira inclusão usando um IF, daí, verifiquei se ela foi feita com um IF, se sim, então é escrito um novo script dentro do IF que faz uma nova inserção. Assim:

```
   public function addUsuario($usuarios_nome, $usuarios_email, $usuarios_senha, $usuarios_permissoes, $usuarios_imagem = null){     

    if ($this->existeEmail($usuarios_email) == false) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuarios_nome, usuarios_email, usuarios_senha, usuarios_permissoes, usuarios_imagem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    $sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
                    $sql -> bindValue(1, $usuarios_nome);
                    $sql -> bindValue(2, $usuarios_email);
                    $sql -> bindValue(3, $usuarios_senha);
                    $sql -> bindValue(4, $usuarios_permissoes);
                    $sql -> bindValue(5, $usuarios_imagem);                                  
                    //$sql -> execute();
                            if($sql->execute()){
                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO colaboradores (colaboradores_usuarios_id, colaboradores_status) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1)";
                                    $sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
                                    $sql -> execute();                                                                  
                            };
                                          return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }           

   }
```